# Is it possible to acces value in TextBox in UserForm(Excel) from python?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I would like to ask you if it is possible to use value form TextBox in UseForm Excel from python using xlwings. For examle i would like to make function in python to make something with the values that are in the TextBoxes.

I tried something like this:

```
wb = xw.Book.caller()
sheet = wb.sheets[0]
value_from_textbox = sheet.shapes['TextBox1'].text_frame2.text_range.text
sheet["A1"].value = value_from_textbox
```

or this:

```
def on_click():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    useform = wb.sheets["UseForm1"]
    textbox1 = useform.controls["Textbox1"]
    text = textbox1.value
    wb.sheets["Sheet1"].range("A1").value = text
```

And i always got an error in excel.

Comment: `value_from_textbox = sheet.shapes('TextBox 1').text` or you can loop the shapes on the sheet `for shape in sheet.shapes:` and print out `.name` as well as `.text` if there are more than one or the name(s) is not known.

Comment: Okay, but it is possible to get the text from an textbox that is in UserForm in ribbon?

Comment: No, that would be outside the scope of Xlwings. You can try looking at [PyXLL](https://www.pyxll.com). It has [some] ability to modify the ribbon though I cannot guarantee it will be able to do what you want in your previous question. This Section deals with modifying the [Ribbon](https://www.pyxll.com/docs/userguide/ribbon.html)